# What's the term to describe a morphism that isn't a composite of morphisms?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, terminology, quiver

Is there a term to describe a morphism in a category that cannot be written as a composition of two (non-identity) morphisms? Naively Googling around I haven't found anyone talking about this, so I don't know if there is an established word for this. I really hope it's the word inde**composable**, since it describes an morphism that is not a **composite**. But the adjectives *prime*, *primitive*, and *irreducible* could also work. I mostly want to make sure I'm don't define such morphisms opposing an established precedent.

Furthermore, is there a name for a category where every morphism can be written as a composite of these "indecomposable" morphisms? Something like a [Krull-Schmidt category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull%E2%80%93Schmidt_category) but for the morphisms instead of the objects. This question is motivated by looking at the functor that takes a quiver and gives you the free category on that quiver. I want the category-theoretic term that describes the morphisms in that free category that came precisely from the arrows of the quiver.

Comment: I don't know of a common name for them, but I'm pretty sure "indecomposable" would be immediately understood.

Comment: Every morphism can be *uniquely* written as a composite of irreducibles if and only if your category is free. I'm not immediately sure what kind of category has every morphism just *some* composite of irreducibles...not sure it's a useful concept. Reedy categories are a class of examples, but certainly aren't exhaustive. Note that such a category will always be skeletal, so you might rather ask for a morphism which isn't a composite of two non-isomorphisms. Or maybe not!

Comment: For the specific case of the indecomposable arrows in a free category, I would probably call them "generators" (or possibly "generating arrows" if I was afraid of conflicting with [some other terminology](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/separator)). They literally are generators in the usual algebraic sense if you view a (small) category as a multi-sorted essentially algebraic theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the answer does not appear to be an immediate *Yes*, I figure this CW answer should be made to collect everyone's suggestions and comments.

- Calling such morphisms *indecomposable* is alright for the reason mentioned in the question.
- As [Derek Elkins says in the comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3016417/whats-the-term-to-describe-a-morphism-that-isnt-a-composite-of-morphisms#comment6221111_3016417), one could call such morphisms *generators*, or *generating morphisms*, since they literally are generators for the rest of the morphisms in the usual algebraic sense, when viewing your (small) category as a [multi-sorted essential algebraic theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/algebraic+theory#essentially_algebraic_theories).
- You *might* be inspired to call them *primitive* morphisms, after the primitive elements of a coalgebra, the elements $x$ such that $\Delta(x) = x\otimes 1 + 1 \otimes x$. Calling them this isn't ideal though. I think that you can't quite regard the path algebra of a quiver (paths in a category) as a coalgebra, so the analogy has some holes.